# Multiple relations to same table from different models

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I would like to have a simple and reusable way of sharing a relations with a specific table with different models. What I would like to do is the possibility to specify a table, with a foreign key column such as "parent_id" and then associate this table/model to several models in my app. Is there a way to do this in cake, and which is the best way? I guess I would need an additional column in this table, to specify which is the table every row is linked to, e.g.:

Table1

id     0      1      2
name   name0  name1  name2
...

Table2

id     0      1      2
name   name0  name1  name2
...

Common_table:

id             0       1
...
parent_id      0       0
parent_table   Table1  Table2

I hope the explanation above made sense, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes

when you create a relationship you can also set the conditions

An example could be an application in which you have many models that can be commented, so they all are in a hasMany relationship with `Comment` Model.

You can create a column in comments table storing the name of the model being commented and a `parent_id` column storing the id.

So the comments table would tipically be something like

```
id | parent_id | model_name | comment_text         | user_id
---+-----------+------------+----------------------+-------
1  | 15        | Post       | I like this Post     | 3
1  | 15        | Post       | I like this Post too | 5
2  | 19        | Receipt    | This receipt is good | 3
```

in your `Post` Model you can do

```
public hasMany =array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.model_name' => 'Post')
    )
```

in your `Receipt` Model you can do

```
public hasMany =array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.model_name' => 'Receipt')
    )
```

and so on

Comment: Seems promising... Is there a way to automate stuff like obtaining all comments for the linked parent, saving etc? I guess I should use a Behavior?

Comment: yes, a behavior could be the right choiche. But with my code above when your do something like `$this->Post->find('first', ...)` you get a Post with all his comments

Comment: Any hint on how to do it in a behavior?

Comment: @cpl Your question it's a little generic... what exactly do you want to achieve?